# Linking to display form after pulling Announcements with REST

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer

```
function ShowPopup() {
        var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
        options.width = 800;
        options.height = 600;
        options.allowMaximize = false;
        options.url = "https://sitename.sharepoint.com/samplepoc/Lists/Announcements/DispForm.aspx";
        SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
        };

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    headers: {
       'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
    },
    url: '/samplepoc/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(\'Announcements\')/items',
    success: function(data){    
        console.log(data.d.results);
        var info = data.d.results;
        announce(info.pop(), '#leftboxmain');
        announce(info.pop(), '#leftboxleft');
        announce(info.pop(), '#leftboxright');

    }
});

var announce = function(item, location){
    //console.log(this);
    $(location).append('<h2>' + item.AnnouncementDate + '</h2><h3><a href="javascript:ShowPopup();">' + item.Title + '</a></h3>' + '<div class="anntext">' + item.Body + '</div>');
}
```

Above is the code I currently have - Basically what is happening, is that each time a new announcement is created the dashboard updates. I would like the title to open a modal with that announcements display form showing.

Given the fact this will be constantly updated, I can't include a URL with a specific ID - so my question is whether there is a way to link each announcement with it's own display form or if there is another method I could try?

I hope this makes sense - I'm sort of learning as I go with SP Designer so if I need to clarify anything please do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the announcements to pop up in real time you need to poll the list at intervals and take action whenever a new one shows up. The function you're looking for is `setInterval` - I suggest looking into documentation on that.

You also need to figure out when a new item shows up, so you'll need to store the ID of the newest item found on page load in a variable. When you fetch announcements in your loop, check to see if you've got an ID higher than that value. If so, you've found a new one, and you can show it. Be sure to update your highest ID variable when you do this.